# Can't parse my JSON into an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, flask, jinja2

I am working on a parser for a text file. I am trying to parse some JSON strings into objects so I can easily display some different values on a webapp page (using flask). I am passing the strings into my html page using jinja2, and trying to parse them objects in javascript.

```js
function parseLine(x) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(x);
    document.write(obj.timestamp1);
}
```

I am getting this error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

in the console browser. I have found many stackoverflow questions with that error, but the suggestions do not fix my problem.

If I use a dummy string, surrounded by single quotes: `'{"test": "1234"}'` it works fine.

If I need to include anymore information I can.

Comment: can you share what `x` looks like?

Comment: You've likely constructed your string incorrectly.  Please share that value with us so we can move to help you.  I agree with gurvinder372... we need to see x.

Comment: here is an example of x:


{"time": ["2016-01-05", "08:12:28.680"], "message": "test.", "id": "1234", "level": "DEBUG"}


edit: Why did my post get downvoted so hard? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues but was able to solve it using this way using the

> reviver parameter on JSON.parse()

```js
var Person = {} 
// an  empty person object
//sample json object, can also be from a server  
var sampleJson = {'name': 'Peter',    'age': "20"};
//use the javascript Object.assign method to transfer the json from the source[JSON.parse]to the target[Person]
// the source is JSON.parse which take a string argument and a function reviver for the key value pair
Object.assign(Person, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sampleJson),
        function (k, v) {            
        //we return the key value pair for the json                      
           return k, v
        }
     ) 
 )
console.log(Person.name) //Peter
console.log(Person.age) // age
```